# How do I send multipart form data in an HTTP request (for Watson NLC training)?

Tags: go, http-headers, nlp, content-type, ibm-watson

I'm writing application that'll use Watson Natural Language Classifier ("NLC").
When I send an HTTP POST request against the [*v1/classifiers* URI path](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/#create_classifier) with the following request message body, the server responds with status code 415 (*Unsupported Media Type*):

```
--04fef47728eb08148fe9c7b18dd42b75abd75ebf752fd3412a85aa3af075
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="training_data"; filename="data.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

How hot is it today?;temperature
Is it hot outside?;temperature
Will it be uncomfortably hot?;temperature
Will it be sweltering?;temperature
How cold is it today?;temperature
Is it cold outside?;temperature
Will it be uncomfortably cold?;temperature
Will it be frigid?;temperature
What is the expected high for today?;temperature
What is the expected temperature?;temperature
Will high temperatures be dangerous?;temperature
Is it dangerously cold?;temperature
When will the heat subside?;temperature
Is it hot?;temperature
Is it cold?;temperature
How cold is it now?;temperature
Will we have a cold day today?;temperature
When will the cold subside?;temperature
What highs are we expecting?;temperature
What lows are we expecting?;temperature
Is it warm?;temperature
Is it chilly?;temperature
What's the current temp in Celsius?;temperature
What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?;temperature
--04fef47728eb08148fe9c7b18dd42b75abd75ebf752fd3412a85aa3af075
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="training_metadata"; filename="metadata.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{"language": "en"}
```

The 415 status code suggests a problem with the content type, but it *seems* like all the MIME types are correct.

My code (written in Go):

```
func (w WatsonClassifier) createFormFile(writer *multipart.Writer, fieldname string, filename string, contentType string) (io.Writer, error)     {
    h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    h.Set("Content-Disposition",
        fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`,
            fieldname, filename))
    h.Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    return writer.CreatePart(h)
}

func (w WatsonClassifier) request(method string, apiUrl string, body io.Reader) (string, error) {
    url := w.url + "/" + apiUrl
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(w.username, w.password)
    client := http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        answer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(answer))
        return "", errors.New("Watson returned wrong status code : " + resp.Status)
    }
    answer, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(answer), nil
}

func (w WatsonClassifier) Train(data []ClassifierCategory) (Classifier, error) {
    table := w.buildTable(data)
    str := w.buildCsv(data)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
    data_part, err := w.createFormFile(writer, "training_data", "data.csv", "text/csv")
    if err != nil {
        return WatsonClassifier{}, err
    }
    data_part.Write([]byte(str))
    metadata_part, err := w.createFormFile(writer, "training_metadata", "metadata.json", "application/json")
    if err != nil {
        return WatsonClassifier{}, err
    }
    metadata_json := "{\"language\": \"" + w.Language + "\"}"
    metadata_part.Write([]byte(metadata_json))
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
    answer, err := w.request("POST", "v1/classifiers", buf)
    if err != nil {
        return WatsonClassifier{}, err
    }
    fmt.Println(answer)
    return WatsonClassifier{}, nil
}
```

Comment: Also, given curl request (curl -u "{username}":"{password}" -F training_data=@train.csv -F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"My Classifier\"}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers") works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that *curl* is sending a "Content-Type" header of `multipart/form-data`. Your Go program is sending a "Content-Disposition" header with just `form-data` (note the difference, it lacking the leading `multipart` composite top-level media type), but it doesn't take care of sending the correct "Content-Type" header for the containing HTTP request.

Go's `multipart.Writer` type's [`CreateFormFile` method does the same](https://golang.org/src/mime/multipart/writer.go?s=2132:2207#L127), but again, that's only part of the job:

```
h.Set("Content-Disposition",
        fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`,
                escapeQuotes(fieldname), escapeQuotes(filename)))
```

To get the proper "Content-Type" header value, you need to use [`multipart.Writer.FormDataContentType`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Writer.FormDataContentType). To put that value to use, you'll need to get your `multipart.Writer` into your `WatsonClassifier.request` method, so that you can set the content type on your `http.Request` instance:

```
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
```

Alternately, add another parameter to `WatsonClassifier.request` for the content type, and pass the result of `FormDataContentType` as the argument from the call site in `WatsonClassifier.Train`.

Let us know if that does the trick.